# Why the version of groovy related to the version of spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, groovy

When I upgrade the version of Spring boot from 2.4.x to 3.0.0, then this error occurs:

```
Downloading from amaxgs-libs-release: http://{server-IP}:{port}/artifactory/libs-release/org/apache/groovy/groovy-bom/3.0.9/groovy-bom-3.0.9.pom

Downloading from amaxgs-libs-snapshot: http://{server-IP}:{port}/artifactory/libs-snapshot/org/apache/groovy/groovy-bom/3.0.9/groovy-bom-3.0.9.pom

Downloading from vaadin-addons: https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons/org/apache/groovy/groovy-bom/3.0.9/groovy-bom-3.0.9.pom

Downloading from aliyunmaven: https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/central/org/apache/groovy/groovy-bom/3.0.9/groovy-bom-3.0.9.pom

[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:

[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.apache.groovy:groovy-bom:pom:3.0.9 in amaxgs-libs-release (http://{server-IP}:{port}/artifactory/libs-release) @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.0.0, D:\Repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-dependencies\3.0.0\spring-boot-dependencies-3.0.0.pom, line 2141, column 19
```

What is wrong with my POM file? The POM file exists in the Central Repository.

Comment: It isn't in your companies repositories and it apparently doesn't resolve it automatically from central.

Answer (score -1):

You have not specified groovy in your POM file
Therefore, you must specify the groovy version in POM.xml as shown below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Groovy is already in the pom (probably as a transitive dependency) and it cannot be downloaded from the repositories because it isn't there and the internal one doesn't mirror central fully. Adding it again as a dependency won't help.

Comment: @M.Deinum It is not a question of being or not being. The issue is that we have to specify the existing version in the POM file.

Comment: No you don't... Also the error message is clearly stating that it cannot download a dependency.

Comment: i let spring boot manage the version of my groovy like this `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-groovy-templates</artifactId>
        </dependency>` ,and then i fix it. This problem  seems to be related to the way Groovy depends .